# Looking for the giant list of municipalities of the world

Tags: data

I have a newbie question, but one that didn't seem to match earlier questions. I need a complete list of municipalities and their location for a bunch of countries. The data I need is just name, country, and approximate latlong. I very much need the list to include down to tiny municipalities (population as low as 100 or so).

Is there a well-known location for such lists? I'm OK with paying, but of course would prefer free even if the data is a decade out of date. This is for a project using programming (hopefully Python), not a map-based GIS system.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, we are more of a *problem-solving* site than a list compilation one. You should probably research this topic via Google (which will likely turn up GeoNames) or over in [opendata.se]

Comment: Thanks. I had taken the tour, but didn't really get that this is "more of a problem-solving site than a list compilation one". That makes sense. I of course searched Google, with nothing useful coming up. I'll look into GeoNames and OpenData.

Answer (score -1):

[GeoNames](https://www.geonames.org/) Hint for the future: search for "city names" not "municipality names"....

Comment: There's two different "GeoNames" -- geonames.org, and GeoNames from NGA (nga.mil). The former was derived from the latter, but now seems to be independently maintained.

Comment: geonames.org is in the link I gave. From their web site, they started from many different sources (including the NGA). The NGA site appears to not be maintained.